# How can I scroll through the pages of full-screen PDF viewer in TeXShop?

Tags: texshop

When I put the PDF viewer into full-screen mode (for example full-screen by itself or with the editor using El Capitan's split view feature, which is actually what I want to do) I can no longer scroll through the pages of the document. To view other pages I have to open the (now hidden because of full-screen mode) toolbar and use the page up/down buttons.

Is there a way to use the full-screen split-view feature with the editor on the left and PDF on the right (or somehow dock the PDF viewer into the editor so that I can full-screen that window) and still be able to scroll through the pages in the PDF? I basically want the editor on the left and PDF on the right, with no window decoration/toolbars, etc. getting in the way, but I'm totally new to TeX so if there's another way to get this, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Just so people do not have to read through the comments, the *actual* answer to this question is:

> Right click inside the PDF viewer and select "Single Page Continuous".

Thank you @SimosNones!

Answer (score 1):

It works just fine in my El Capitan installation. I advance through the pages by pressing space for the next page and shift+space for the previous page. You need to click on the pdf viewer, to put the focus on that window. Otherwise, the space keystroke will be passed to the editor.
**You can also tick the option Do not scroll in the preview pane, to be able to change pages by scrolling with the mouse.**

Comment: The "Do not scroll" option has no effect on whether you can use the mouse to scroll or not in full screen mode. When the viewer is full-screen, it will only view page-by-page, it won't scroll.

Comment: I haven't tried Full Screen mode (will test later) but you can certainly place the individual Source and Preview Windows side by side and make that the default.

Comment: If you want a continuous scroll, just right click on the PDF viewer and select single page continuous. And you can use your mouse for free scrolling. The arrow keys, the space bar and the pageup/down keys work too.